# Story where the main characters travel to Oz and mess up the story

Tags: story-identification

I'm looking for a story where the main characters, fairly sure that they were some kids and a grandfather, who often traveled into books. (This happened in other books in the series, which I haven't read.) In this one, they traveled to Oz. They landed with Dorothy, where they realized that their extra weight threw the house off and it didn't kill the Wicked Witch. They then spent the rest of the book trying to fix it.

This was in English, I have no idea when it came out. I think that story was aimed at ~11/12 year olds.

Comment: Probably not a Doctor Who episode.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After scouring my bookcases for hours, and then searching through my Kindle, I finally found it in my Archived Items.

***The Wiz Kids of Oz*, by Robert Bresloff**

[image: Cover of "The Wiz Kids of Oz" by Robert Bresloff. The cover shows a green background, with a framed picture on a wall. The picture shows the main Oz characters, including Dorothy, Toto, and the Scarecrow.]

To quote the [Amazon description](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00CDG4S5W):

> In book three of the "Bound into the Classics" series, Grandpa Max and the boys take another magical trip into one of the best loved classics of all time. But, when Bobby, Fritzy, Keith, and Grandpa Max land in L. Frank Baum's The Wonderful Wizard of Oz, things go horribly wrong, possibly changing the beloved classic forever. So settle in for an unforgettable ride through the magical kingdom of Oz as our heroes help Dorothy, Toto, the Scarecrow, the Tin Woodman, and the Cowardly Lion reach the Emerald City and save The Wonderful Wizard of Oz.